# Pull Down Map Android - Facebook Effect

Tags: android, animation

I am currently working on a prototype where I have two fragments in a LinearLayout.

Here is what the xml looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
            >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_weight=".70"
            >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The top fragment is a map fragment and the bottom fragment is just a list of items. I am trying to expand the map when the user clicks on the fragment. The height changes from .3 to 1. Currently I have tried to animate and change the height of the fragment, this gives horrible performance. I have looked around and found that Facebook Nearby Places does this effect smoothly. Should I be using the ScaleAnimation class to do this? Thank you for your help.

Edit:
Foursquare has the same type of effect. When click on the map it scales smoothly into fullscreen I have attached a screen shot.

Here is an example of what it looks like:
http://im.tech2.in.com/gallery/2013/apr/foursquareforandroid_041425247544_640x360.jpg

Comment: I think I have found a solution. I will post an answer soon.

Comment: Could you share your solution?